# the difference between refresh a page and be redirect to a page

Tags: javascript, http, url, html

i was reading the html of this page [here](http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/descargar-mp3/no-puedo-vivir-sin-ti-operaci%C3%B3n-triunfo-cepeda-aitana-oca%C3%B1a) because i wanna do a personal program to download music since my phone, the problem is the following:

here is the html of the page:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximun-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us">

        <title>Descargar No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña MP3 Gratis - BajarMp3Gratis.NeT</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Escuchar y Descargar No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña Mp3, bajar mp3 fácil y rápido desde tu celular totalmente gratis.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="descargar musica no puedo vivir sin ti operación triunfo cepeda aitana ocaña, no puedo vivir sin ti operación triunfo cepeda aitana ocaña en MP3, no puedo vivir sin ti operación triunfo cepeda aitana ocaña musica, no puedo vivir sin ti operación triunfo cepeda aitana ocaña gratis, musica gratis, musica mp3, descargar mp3, bajar mp3" />
        <link rel="image_src" href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/cdn.img/share-img.jpg" />

        <meta property="og:title" content="Descargar No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña MP3 Gratis - BajarMp3Gratis.NeT" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Escuchar y Descargar No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña Mp3, bajar mp3 fácil y rápido desde tu celular totalmente gratis." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/cdn.img/share-img.jpg" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="descargar musica">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Descargar Musica Gratis">

        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="kfgrZ807sBKeQpwfPummX5C12hFp5rAQ8anX5SieHO4" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP" />
        <meta name="revisit" content="1 days" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/favicon.ico">
        <base href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/estilo.css?v=1521131029">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/js/jquery-min.js?vr=1532745035"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <div class="contenta">
                <h2 class="top-navigation">               
                 <a href="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/" title="Descargar Musica Gratis">Bajar Mp3 Gratis</a>
                </h2>
                <form id="search" method="post" class="form" action="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/?buscar=">
                    <div id="form_wrapper">
                        <input id="input" type="text" name="buscar" placeholder="Buscar artista o cancion..." autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <button>BUSCAR</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </div>
        </header>
    <input type="hidden" id="token" value="3212322d3038,3525432d3038,3524152d3038,3415552d3038,3452142d3038,3244252d3038,3442352d3038,3533142d3038,3551132d3038,3215552d3038,3325412d3038,3234322d3038,3212532d3038,3414512d3038,3144232d3038,3313112d3038,3414122d3038,3543352d3038,3443542d3038,3435432d3038,3352442d3038,3513422d3038,3435332d3038,3423312d3038,3331322d3038,3233422d3038,3541552d3038,3355352d3038,3523132d3038,3253212d3038">

    <div class="contenedor grupo main">
      <div class="contenido">
    <div class="postlist">
          <h1>Descargar No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña MP3 Gratis</h1>

    <div class="description">
    <p>Descargar <strong>No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña</strong> MP3 en alta calidad (HD) <strong>20</strong> resultados, lo nuevo de sus canciones y videos que estan de moda este 2018, bajar musica de No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti Operación Triunfo Cepeda Aitana Ocaña en diferentes formatos de audio mp3 y video disponibles; <strong> No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti - Cepeda Y Aitana  Gala 1  Ot 2017</strong> MP3 subido por <strong>Operación Triunfo Oficial</strong> tamaño <strong>7.38 MB</strong>, duración <strong>3:09</strong> calidad de 192.
    </p>

    </div>  
     <iframe style="height: 1px; width: 1px;" id="video" class="full" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/U3TCIcHqKQM?controls=0&amp;amp;disablekb=0&amp;amp;autoplay=0&amp;amp;wmode=opaque&amp;amp;showinfo=0&amp;amp;rel=0&amp;amp;cc_load_policy=0&amp;amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;amp;iv_load_policy=3" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe> 
      <ul class="play_lista playlist-new">
      <li data-id="U3TCIcHqKQM">
                <span class="i"><i class="ic ic-play"></i></span>
                <span class="n"> No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti - Cepeda Y Aitana  Gala 1  Ot 2017 <i>1</i></span>
                <a href="#" data-id="U3TCIcHqKQM" target="_black" rel="nofollow"  class="d"><i class="ic ic-download"> </i> Descargar</a>
                <!--<span class="ldown d"><i class="ic ic-download "> </i> Descargar</span>-->

                </li>
    <li data-id="kqJw9wdZ_ng">
                <span class="i"><i class="ic ic-play"></i></span>
                <span class="n">No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti - Aitana Y Cepeda  Ot 2017  Ot Fiesta <i>2</i></span>
                <a href="#" data-id="kqJw9wdZ_ng" target="_black" rel="nofollow"  class="d"><i class="ic ic-download"> </i> Descargar</a>
                <!--<span class="ldown d"><i class="ic ic-download "> </i> Descargar</span>-->

                </li>
    <li data-id="mwikkxAcDQ4">
                <span class="i"><i class="ic ic-play"></i></span>
                <span class="n">No Puedo Vivir Sin Ti - Aitana Y Cepeda  <i>3</i></span>
                <a href="#" data-id="mwikkxAcDQ4" target="_black" rel="nofollow"  class="d"><i class="ic ic-download"> </i> Descargar</a>
                <!--<span class="ldown d"><i class="ic ic-download "> </i> Descargar</span>-->
```

<...............(if you want more code go to the link, but i thought it was not important to answer my question)....>

```
    En <strong>BajarMp3Gratis.Net</strong> NO apoyamos a la piratería musical, ya que los mp3s aquí no se encuentran alojadas en nuestro servidor son de sitios publicos de internet. Gracias por Tu Visita.</p></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('click','.ldown', function(){
        var base = $(this).parent();
        $('.temporal').remove();
        base.after('<div class="temporal"><center style="color: #999;"> Opcion 1</br> <iframe src="https://www.convertmp3.io/es/widget/button/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+ base.data('id') +'&amp;color=a88600" style="width:100%;height:60px;border:0;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no"></iframe></center><center style="color: #999;"> Opcion 2 <div class="download"><iframe id="myframe" src="https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v='+ base.data('id') +'#download" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-presentation allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" scrolling="no" style="border: none;width: 82px;display: block;height: 40px;margin: 0 auto;}"></iframe></div></center></div>');
        return false;

});

    </script>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-118882463-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-118882463-1');
    </script>

    <script src="http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/js/script.js?v=1506889502"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function PerroCSM(url, params){
     var form = document.createElement("form");
     form.setAttribute("method", "post");
     form.setAttribute("action", url);
     form.setAttribute("target", '_black');
     for (var i in params) {
     if (params.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     var input = document.createElement('input');
     input.type = 'hidden', input.name = i, input.value = params[i];
     form.appendChild(input);
     }
     }
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     window.open("post.htm", '_black');
     form.submit();
     document.body.removeChild(form);
    }
    $(document).on('click','.d', function(){
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     var token = $('#token').val();
     var porciones = token.split(',');
     PerroCSM("http://www.ytdata.stream/"+porciones[Math.floor(Math.random() * porciones.length)], { 'id' : id });
     return false;
    });
    </script>
```

so after show all this long code here is my question: if you go to this [page](http://www.bajarmp3gratis.net/descargar-mp3/no-puedo-vivir-sin-ti-operaci%C3%B3n-triunfo-cepeda-aitana-oca%C3%B1a) that i give you up of all this code and press the link that i will show you now in blue:

[image]

you will be redirect to this other page (that is ready to download the music):

[image]

now if you refresh the page or go to this [link](http://www.ytdata.stream/3442352d3038) you will find the next image:

[image]

so i don t understand how a page can have 2 state to the same URL?(one if you go directly and other if you go since another page)

Answer (score 0):

> *Refresh* will refresh a same loaded page.
>
> *Redirect* will load the other page.

Comment: so why for the same url that page have two state?